# Can we apply a Action on another Action in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to run some basic spark applications.

Can we apply a Action on another Action ?

or

Action  can be applied only on Transformed RDD?

```
  val numbersRDD = sc.parallelize(Array(1,2,3,4,5));
  val topnumbersRDD = numbersRDD.take(2)

 scala> topnumbersRDD.count
 <console>:17: error: missing arguments for method count in    trait             TraversableOnce;
   follow this method with `_' if you want to treat it as a partially       applied function
          topnumbersRDD.count
                        ^
```

I would like to know why I am getting this above  error .

Also what can I do if I want to find the count of first 2 numbers.. I need output as 2 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actions can be applied on `RDD` and `DataFrame`, the `take` method returns an Array, you could use length or size of array to count the elements.

If you want to choose datas with a condition, you could use `filter` and that returns a new RDD

Comment: Ok.. I would like to take the first 2 elements  from numbersRDD and want to apply some more transformations on that . How do I do that ?        I tried numbersRDD.take(2).filter .. it throws me error

Comment: filter should be done on RDD like: numbersRDD.filter

Comment: if you want the array length you could try numbersRDD.take(2).length

Comment: I am not looking for length.. I am looking to keep the first 2 elements alone so that I will apply some other tarnsformations on those 2 elements alone .

Comment: You could do val topnumbersRDD = sc.parallelize(numbersRDD.take(2)) and it create a new RDD with first 2 elements